# Why is RISC-V GCC breaking my code when optimizations are enabled?

Tags: c, gcc, system-calls, inline-assembly, riscv

I have the following C code for 32-bit RISC-V:

```
static void test(uint32_t key, uint32_t chr, uint32_t state)
{
    char s[2];

    if(state != KEYSTATE_PRESSED) { return; }
    if(!isprint(chr)) { return; }

    font_string(10, 200, "Key Pressed", FONT_MONOSPACE, 0xFFFF, 0x0000);

    s[0] = chr;
    s[1] = '\0';
    font_string(10, 10, s, FONT_MONOSPACE, 0xFFFF, 0x00FF);
}
```

When compiling with -O0, it works correctly and prints the
character that was pressed.

With -O2 however, the only "Key Pressed" is drawn on the display. I assume that this
is not a compiler bug and that I have made a mistake somewhere.

The suspicious thing to me is, that the generated assembly for the function `test`
does not contain a single "Store" instruction which would be necessary to put the character into the array:

(Note: Everything has been inlined here)

```
00000090 <test>:
  90:   00100793            li  a5,1
  94:   00f60463            beq a2,a5,9c <test+0xc>
  98:   00008067            ret
  9c:   fe058593            add a1,a1,-32
  a0:   05e00793            li  a5,94
  a4:   feb7eae3            bltu    a5,a1,98 <test+0x8>
  a8:   ff010113            add sp,sp,-16
  ac:   00a00513            li  a0,10
  b0:   0c800593            li  a1,200
  b4:   0e800613            li  a2,232
  b8:   0ff00693            li  a3,255
  bc:   00000713            li  a4,0
  c0:   ffff07b7            lui a5,0xffff0
  c4:   00300893            li  a7,3
  c8:   00000073            ecall
  cc:   00a00513            li  a0,10
  d0:   00a00593            li  a1,10
  d4:   00c10613            add a2,sp,12
  d8:   0ff78793            add a5,a5,255 # ffff00ff <_event_key+0xfffefffb>
  dc:   00000073            ecall
  e0:   01010113            add sp,sp,16
  e4:   00008067            ret
```

The `font_string` function (and everything it calls) is defined as follows:

```
static void font_string(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, const char *s,
    uint32_t font_id, uint32_t fg, uint32_t bg)
{
    font_string_len(x, y, s, GFX_STRING_MAX_LEN, font_id, fg, bg);
}

static void font_string_len(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, const char *s,
    uint32_t len, uint32_t font_id, uint32_t fg, uint32_t bg)
{
    syscall6(SYSCALL_GFX_STRING,
        x, y, (uint32_t)s, len, font_id, (fg << 16) | bg);
}

static inline uint32_t syscall6(uint32_t id,
    uint32_t a0, uint32_t a1, uint32_t a2, uint32_t a3, uint32_t a4, uint32_t a5)
{
    register uint32_t ra0 asm("a0") = a0;
    register uint32_t ra1 asm("a1") = a1;
    register uint32_t ra2 asm("a2") = a2;
    register uint32_t ra3 asm("a3") = a3;
    register uint32_t ra4 asm("a4") = a4;
    register uint32_t ra5 asm("a5") = a5;
    register uint32_t ra7 asm("a7") = id;

    asm volatile("ecall"
        : "+r"(ra0)
        : "r"(ra1), "r"(ra2), "r"(ra3), "r"(ra4), "r"(ra5),
        "r"(ra7));

    return ra0;
}
```

Compiler version is 12.2.0

Comment: The simple fix is to add a `"memory"` clobber to your `asm` statement.  The fun way is to use separate `asm` statements for each system call which have dummy `"m"`, `"+m"`, or `"=m"` operands with dereferenced pointer inputs to let the compiler know *which* memory is an input or output for that specific system call.  (With a fixed or variable size as appropriate to the system call, e.g. a `struct stat` has a known size but a `read` or `write` would need a cast to pointer-to-VLA and deref.)